# How would you add multiple textclips to a video at diffrent timestamps using moviepy in python?

Tags: python, video, time, moviepy

Say I have `textOne`, `textTwo`, and `textThree`. Each varible is 10 seconds long, and have to be inserted every 15 seconds. For example, you have `textOne` starting at 00:00, and finishing at 00:10. Then you wait 5 seconds and `textTwo` is inserted for another 10 seconds, and so on. How would you go about achieving this?

Note that in a real application of this you wouldn't just have set numbers like 10 seconds or wait every 15 seconds, each one would probably be different.

Using Python 3.8.5, vs code, and the latest version of moviepy to date

Comment: set_start and CompositeVideoClip

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
from moviepy.editor import *  

picture = VideoFileClip("img.jpg", audio=False).set_duration(50)

textOne = "First Line!"
textTwo = "Second Caption!!!!"
textThree = "Third one!!!"

texts = [textOne, textTwo, textThree]

step = 15 #each 15 sec: 0, 15, 30
duration = 10
t = 0
txt_clips = []
for text,i in zip(texts,range(0,3)):
  txt_clip = TextClip(text,fontsize = 40, color='white')
  txt_clip = txt_clip.set_start(t)
  txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(duration)
  txt_clips.append(txt_clip)  
  t += step
  
audio = AudioFileClip(r"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3").subclip(0,50)

video_with_new_audio = picture.set_audio(audio)

final_video = CompositeVideoClip([video_with_new_audio,txt_clips[0],txt_clips[1],txt_clips[2]])

final_video.write_videofile("TEXT.mp4")
```

For more flexibility, you can use not range(0,3) etc., but lists with the time points and durations, like with the captions; something like that:

```
starts = [0, 15, 30] # or whatever
durations = [10, 5, 7] 

for text,t,duration in zip(texts, starts, durations): 
    txt_clip = TextClip(text,fontsize = 40, color='white')
    txt_clip = txt_clip.set_start(t)
    txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(duration)
    txt_clips.append(txt_clip)
```