# Add text overlay to start of each clip and then concatenate them. Moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

My goal is to add a text overlay to a series of clips at a given timestamp and then concatenate them all to make a single video. Currently, the video that is output as 'movie.mp4' only plays the first text overlay and none of the others.

I have looked at other posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209725/how-would-you-add-multiple-textclips-to-a-video-at-diffrent-timestamps-using-mov)) to try to recreate this but I have been unsuccessful.
In the comments for `create_final_video(clips, texts, totalDuration)` you can see what else I have tried in order to concatenate the clips. This method also requires removing `clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip, text]).set_duration(float(clip_data['clipDuration']))`. This second version concatenates the videos but the text overlay doesn't have its position set to the bottom left but to the top right instead, and the text overlays play back to back after each other rather than at the end of each clip.

Below is the first version:

```
import os
import json
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, concatenate_videoclips, vfx, TextClip

# reads clip valid clip names from file
def read_valid_clips_list():

# gets clip data
def get_clip_data(filename):

def create_clips(clip_list):
    clips = []
    texts = []
    currentDuration = 0
    for filename in clip_list:
        filename = filename.strip()
        clip_data = get_clip_data(filename)
        video_file_path = os.path.join(PATH_TO_RAW_CLIPS, filename)
        
        # create video clip
        clip = VideoFileClip(video_file_path)
        clip = clip.set_duration(float(clip_data['clipDuration']))
        clip = clip.fx(vfx.fadein, .1).fx(vfx.fadeout, .15)

        # create text overlay for clip
        text = create_text_overlay(clip_data, currentDuration)
        
        # combine clip and text before concatenation
        clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip, text]).set_duration(float(clip_data['clipDuration']))
        currentDuration += float(clip_data['clipDuration'])

        texts.append(text)
        clips.append(clip)

    return clips, texts, currentDuration

def create_text_overlay(clip_data, currentDuration):
    streamerName = str(clip_data.get('streamerName'))

    text_clip = TextClip(txt = streamerName, font = FONT_PATH, size = (400,0), color = 'rgb(145, 70, 255)')
    tc_width, tc_height = text_clip.size

    print(currentDuration)
    text_clip = text_clip.set_start(currentDuration)
    text_clip = text_clip.set_position(('left', 'bottom'))
    text_clip = text_clip.set_duration(2.5)
    text_clip = text_clip.crossfadein(0.2).crossfadeout(0.5)

    return text_clip

def create_final_video(clips, texts, totalDuration):
    vid_clips = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose').set_duration(totalDuration)
    # print(type(vid_clips))
    # text_clips = concatenate_videoclips(texts).set_duration(totalDuration)
    # print(type(text_clips))

    # final_movie = CompositeVideoClip([vid_clips, text_clips], size=(1920,1080)).set_duration(totalDuration)
    return vid_clips

def create_movie():
    valid_list = read_valid_clips_list()
    clips, texts, totalDuration = create_clips(valid_list)
    movie = create_final_video(clips, texts, totalDuration)
    
    return movie

movie = create_movie()
movie.write_videofile('VideoCompilation\VideoFiles\\videos\movie.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `text_clip = text_clip.set_start(0)`